# Isotope combine filter and search field with and logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, masonry, jquery-isotope

I have a code on codepen that works for filtering an isotope grid and works also for search in a isotope grid.

The filters are made with checkboxes and logic, so that some checkboxes cannot activate on the same time (male/female). However, this is not important…

The filters are working.
The search field works (unfortunately only if I first no activate an filter)

First wish:
I want to combine filter and search with AND logic. 
Example when I insert in the search box 'martin' then the search result is 'gruber martin', 'hofer martin', 'maier martina'. This is ok.
Then when I also activate 'female', then I would that only 'maier martina' remain (search=martin AND filter=female)

But my code in this case do not remember the search an set only the filter :-(

Second wish: the search field should work at all times, not only when no filter is active.

It would be great if someone could help me.

Thanks..

HTML:

```
<button id="shuffle">shuffle</button>
<div class="button-group filter-button-group">
  <div class="btn">
    <input name="male" value=".male" id="male" type="checkbox">
    <label for="male">male</label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <input name="female" value=".female" id="female" type="checkbox">
    <label for="female">female</label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <input name="de" value=".de" id="de" type="checkbox">
    <label for="de">de</label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <input name="it" value=".it" id="it" type="checkbox">
    <label for="it">it</label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <input name="en" value=".en" id="en" type="checkbox">
    <label for="en">en</label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <input name="has-website" value=".has-website" id="has-website" type="checkbox">
    <label for="has-website">has-website</label>
  </div>
</div>
<input class="quicksearch" placeholder="Search" type="text">
<div class="blog_wrapper isotope_wrapper myclass">
  <div class="posts_group lm_wrapper masonry tiles col-6 isotope" style="position: relative; height: 10615.1px;">
    <div class="post-item isotope-item  de it male has-website" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
      <div class="post-photo-wrapper scale-with-grid"> </div>
      <div class="post-desc-wrapper">
        <div class="post-desc">
          <div class="post-head"></div>
          <div class="post-title">
            <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="#">gruber martin</a></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="post-excerpt"><span class="excerpt-hellip">Lorem ipsum […]</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-item isotope-item  de it female" style="position: absolute; left: 179px; top: 0px;">
      <div class="post-photo-wrapper scale-with-grid"> </div>
      <div class="post-desc-wrapper">
        <div class="post-desc">
          <div class="post-head"></div>
          <div class="post-title">
            <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="#">maier erna</a></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="post-excerpt"><span class="excerpt-hellip">dolor sit […]</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-item isotope-item  de it male" style="position: absolute; left: 359px; top: 0px;">
      <div class="post-photo-wrapper scale-with-grid"> </div>
      <div class="post-desc-wrapper">
        <div class="post-desc">
          <div class="post-head"></div>
          <div class="post-title">
            <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="#">hofer martin</a></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="post-excerpt"><span class="excerpt-hellip">No text […]</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-item isotope-item  de it male" style="position: absolute; left: 539px; top: 0px;">
      <div class="post-photo-wrapper scale-with-grid"> </div>
      <div class="post-desc-wrapper">
        <div class="post-desc">
          <div class="post-head"></div>
          <div class="post-title">
            <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="#">zwerger josef</a></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="post-excerpt"><span class="excerpt-hellip">Hello […]</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-item isotope-item  it female" style="position: absolute; left: 719px; top: 0px;">
      <div class="post-photo-wrapper scale-with-grid"> </div>
      <div class="post-desc-wrapper">
        <div class="post-desc">
          <div class="post-head"></div>
          <div class="post-title">
            <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="#">gruber susi</a></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="post-excerpt"><span class="excerpt-hellip">bla bla […]</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-item isotope-item  en female" style="position: absolute; left: 899px; top: 0px;">
      <div class="post-photo-wrapper scale-with-grid"> </div>
      <div class="post-desc-wrapper">
        <div class="post-desc">
          <div class="post-head"></div>
          <div class="post-title">
            <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="#">maier martina</a></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="post-excerpt"><span class="excerpt-hellip"> […]</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-item isotope-item male" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 10435px;">
      <div class="post-photo-wrapper scale-with-grid"> </div>
      <div class="post-desc-wrapper">
        <div class="post-desc">
          <div class="post-head"></div>
          <div class="post-title">
            <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="#">maxi john</a></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="post-excerpt"><span class="excerpt-hellip"> […]</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    $('#male').click(function () {
        $('#female').prop('checked', false);
    });
    $('#female').click(function () {
        $('#male').prop('checked', false);
    });


  var grid=$('.isotope');
  var filter=$('.filter-button-group input');
  var qsRegex;


  grid.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
      filter: function() {
          var searchResult = qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
          return searchResult;
    }
  });



  // use value of search field to filter
  var quicksearch = $('.quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
      qsRegex = new RegExp( quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
      grid.isotope();
  }, 200 ) );


  // debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
    function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
      var timeout;
      return function debounced() {
        if ( timeout ) {
          clearTimeout( timeout );
        }
        function delayed() {
          fn();
          timeout = null;
        }
        timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
      }
    }

  $('#shuffle').click(function(){
    grid.isotope('shuffle');
  });


  filter.change(function(){
    var filters = [];
    filter.filter(':checked').each(function(){
      filters.push( this.value );
    });
    // filters = filters.join(', ');    OR
      filters = filters.join('');       //AND
    grid.isotope({ filter: filters });
  });
```

Please see: [code on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpJdad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
    $('#male').click(function () {
        $('#female').prop('checked', false);
    });
    $('#female').click(function () {
        $('#male').prop('checked', false);
    });


  var grid=$('.isotope');
  var filter=$('.filter-button-group input');
  var suche=$('.quicksearch');
  var qsRegex;
  var buttonFilter;

  grid.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
      filter: function() {
         // console.log(searchResult);
          var searchResult = qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
          var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $(this).is( buttonFilter ) : true;

          return searchResult && buttonResult;
    }
  });



  // use value of search field to filter
  var quicksearch = suche.keyup( debounce( function() {
      qsRegex = new RegExp( quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
      grid.isotope();
  }, 200 ) );


  // debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
    function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
      var timeout;
      return function debounced() {
        if ( timeout ) {
          clearTimeout( timeout );
        }
        function delayed() {
          fn();
          timeout = null;
        }
        timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
      };
    }

  $('#shuffle').click(function(){
    grid.isotope('shuffle');
  });



  filter.change(function(){
    var filters = [];

    filter.filter(':checked').each(function(){
      filters.push( this.value );
    });
     //filters = filters.join(', ');    //OR
    filters = filters.join('');         //AND
    buttonFilter = filters;
    grid.isotope();
  });
```

[See full example on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBpYyr)

Answer (score 2):

Same example as above but from de docs :)
https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mCdbD

```
// quick search regex
var qsRegex;
var buttonFilter;

// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  filter: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
    var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
    return searchResult && buttonResult;
  }
});

$('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
  $grid.isotope();
});

// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('#quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
  qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
  $grid.isotope();
}) );


  // change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
  var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
  $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});


// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
  var timeout;
  return function debounced() {
    if ( timeout ) {
      clearTimeout( timeout );
    }
    function delayed() {
      fn();
      timeout = null;
    }
    setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
  };
}
```

Comment: Please add a short text explaining what your answer does so people that are new to the this technology have a chance to understand your code and re-use it

Comment: It combines both filters. If you click the codepen link you'll see very clearly :/

Comment: Having to rely on a link that might break at some point is bad. That's why I consider that a question should still be perfectly valid even if we removed the links to code.